# How to make subtract(difference) using previous columns?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like

| Month | Total | Installment 1 | Installment 2 | Installment 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jan 19 | 500 | 100 | 200 | 100 |
| Feb 19 | 500 | 100 | 100 | 100 |

Is it possible to subtract the value from the previous columns?

The total for Jan19 is 500. Installment 1 is 100. Balance is 400. Then this 400 should be subtracted with Installment 2 and so on.

I've created a sample output.

| Month | Total | Balance 1 | Balance 2 | Balance 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jan 19 | 500 | 400 | 200 | 100 |
| Feb 19 | 500 | 400 | 300 | 200 |

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just use `-`:

```
select month, total,
       (total - installment1) as balance1,
       (total - (installment1 + installment2)) as balance2,
       (total - (installment1 + installment2 + installment3)) as balance3
from t;
```

That said, storing data across *columns* in a SQL table is not the recommended data model for relational databases.  Each installment should be a separate row.

Comment: Thanks but what if we have 30 installments?

Comment: @user12490809 . . . Then you would have 30 expressions.  Carefully read the last paragraph of the answer though.  The issue is your data model.

Comment: I can get that row wise. Then what will be the SQL query

Comment: @user12490809 . . . Ask another question.  This question is answered.